# If li has ul inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, list

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**How do I add `class="parent"` only for `li`, which has `ul` inside it?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in your selector, like this:

```
$("li:has(ul)").addClass("parent")
```